Flutter app crashes when reading from Health Connect for dates with no prior data (health 10.2.0)
My Flutter application encounters a crash while attempting to retrieve health data from Health Connect using the package health ^10.2.0. This issue arises specifically when fetching data for a start date where no data exists, or for any date prior to the specified start date. I've experimented with earlier versions of the health plugin, but the problem persists.
Could this be attributed to a bug within the package, or am I overlooking a step in my implementation? Ideally, the app should be able to request data retrieval from any arbitrary date without prior knowledge of when the first recorded data was captured. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
To Reproduce
Use the plugin to fetch health data for a date range that includes a start date without any data available in Health Connect prior to this date.
The app crashes when attempting to fetch data for the specified start date.
var now = DateTime.now();

var types = [
      HealthDataType.NUTRITION,
    ];
    bool requested = await Health().requestAuthorization(types);

List<HealthDataPoint> healthData = await Health().getHealthDataFromTypes(
        startTime: now.subtract(Duration(days: 4)), endTime: now, types: types);

So today is May 16th, StartTime is then May 12th. The first recorded data available in Health Connect is May 13th, causing it to crash.
Stacktrace
E/AndroidRuntime(17369): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(17369): Process: com.company.app, PID:
E/AndroidRuntime(17369): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(17369):    at cachet.plugins.health.HealthPlugin.convertRecord(HealthPlugin.kt:3297)
E/AndroidRuntime(17369):    at cachet.plugins.health.HealthPlugin$getHCData$1.invokeSuspend(HealthPlugin.kt:2828)
E/AndroidRuntime(17369):    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
E/AndroidRuntime(17369):    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
E/AndroidRuntime(17369):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
E/AndroidRuntime(17369):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(17369):    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E/AndroidRuntime(17369):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/AndroidRuntime(17369):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
E/AndroidRuntime(17369):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(17369):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
E/AndroidRuntime(17369):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
E/AndroidRuntime(17369):    Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@e0bf177, Dispatchers.Main]
I/Process (17369): Sending signal. PID: SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.

Exited.


what does requestAuthorization return?

Just a boolean value, It returns true. the function that is causing the crash is getHealthDataFromTypes @Thomas

I just wanted to rule out that that call might have failed. I didn't see the   // configure the health plugin before use.   Health().configure(useHealthConnectIfAvailable: true); call that is shown in the readme.
Also did you request permissions and add all the stuff that is mentioned in the readme to your manifest?

Yes, I can retreive data when querying from a startdate where there's registered data. The problem is the queries that are prior to any registered data. @Thomas

Is it possible that this package just does not support to query ranges where no data is present? Any other functions to query for available date ranges?

You probably should change the title of your question to better communicate what the problem is

@Leonardbd
Did you found any solution ?
I got the same error NullPointerException, I am requesting this data types :
HealthDataType.BLOOD_GLUCOSE,
HealthDataType.BODY_FAT_PERCENTAGE,
HealthDataType.BODY_MASS_INDEX,
HealthDataType.HEART_RATE,
HealthDataType.HEIGHT,
HealthDataType.WEIGHT,
HealthDataType.NUTRITION,
HealthDataType.BLOOD_OXYGEN,
HealthDataType.ACTIVE_ENERGY_BURNED,

in my case I am sending multiple requests at the same time, that's why I got a crash
